# installing ROS from source, PCL build issue

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to install ROS Fuerte from source on Ubuntu 12.10. I'm having trouble when rosmake -a is trying to make PCL. Does anybody have any tips how to solve this?

Part of the error:

```
   home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointNormal; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZINormal; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointWithRange; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointWithViewpoint; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::getOccupiedVoxelCentersRecursive(const OctreeBranch*, const OctreeKey&, std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> >&) const [with PointT = pcl::PointWithScale; LeafT = pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int>; OctreeT = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeBranch = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeBranch; pcl::octree::OctreePointCloud<PointT, LeafT, OctreeT>::OctreeKey = pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >::OctreeKey]’:
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/src/octree_impl.cpp:60:1:   required from here
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: error: ‘branchHasChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:727:5: note: use ‘this->branchHasChild’ instead
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: error: ‘getBranchChild’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘pcl::octree::Octree2BufBase<int, pcl::octree::OctreeLeafDataTVector<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_pointcloud.hpp:731:5: note: use ‘this->getBranchChild’ instead
make[3]: *** [octree/CMakeFiles/pcl_octree.dir/src/octree_impl.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
make[2]: *** [octree/CMakeFiles/pcl_octree.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gloin/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
make: *** [installed] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47069/installing-ros-from-source,-pcl-build-issue/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building PCL from source is difficult on ROS Fuerte. The sources from pointclouds.org will not work with ROS.

Since you are using Ubuntu, you may be able to build it like Willow Garage does, using their [github PCL repository](https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl).

If that does not work, there are many other questions on answers.ros.org relating to this subject.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2